# Angular-UI datepicker doesn't work within a directive with isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an issue that I believe is related to the isolate scope of my directive.

The Angular-UI popup date picker will not appear again in the directive once a date has been selected from the popup.

Outside the directive, the pop up continues to function correctly even when a date has been selected.

For demonstration purposes, I've used the exact same markup and property for displaying the popup so that the two will influence each other. The same [broken] behaviour in the blob directive can be seen even if the popup and date picker outside the blob are removed.

By having the same markup and `is-open` property, we see the popup appear outside the blob when the calendar icon is clicked inside the blob, so the `open` function appears to be working correctly. It seems the popup in the dialog cannot be re-created once it has been dismissed by selecting a date.

#### Markup:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
<meta name="description" content="Directive Scope" />

  <h1>Directive scope testing</h1>

  <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <blob show="isVisible">
      This is the content. We need in the blob directive, <em>unrelated to the issue being demonstrated</em>.
      <br/>dt in blob scope: {{dt}}
      <hr>
      <input type="text" datepicker-popup="d MMM yyyy" ng-model="$parent.dt" is-open="opened" />
      <button type="button" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </blob>

    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <h3>Outside the dialog</h3>
    <input type="text" datepicker-popup="d MMM yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" />
    <button type="button" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>


  </div>
```

#### Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.directive("blob", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      show:'='
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-show="show"><input type="text" ng-model="test"><br/>{{test}}</div><div ng-transclude></div>'
  };
});

app.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.isVisible = true;

  $scope.open = function($event){
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };
});
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/viqem/5

How can I get the datepicker popup to work consistently inside the `blob` directive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution, which I'm putting here in the hope it'll help someone else, was to also refer to the parent scope in the `is-open` attribute:

```
 ng-model="$parent.dt" is-open="opened" />
```

became

```
 ng-model="$parent.dt" is-open="$parent.opened" />
```

Comment: I've encountered a similar thing where datepicker stops working when wrapped around ngIf. Your approach works but it's more of a hack than a solution. Thanks anyway!