# Angular-UI bootstrap typeahead - Update model when promise resolves

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use [angular-ui.bootstrap.typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) and I want to update it's model when a promise resolves.

I use the `typeahead-on-select` attribute like this

```
typeahead-on-select="select($item,$model))"
```

In `select($item,$model)` some asynchronous stuff is going on, and when a `promise` resolves I want to set the value of the model based on the result.

```
promise.then(function (result) {
    $model.name = result;
    console.log($model);  // <-- $model IS updated but the view doesn't react on it
}
```

I have tried using `$apply` different places, but it doesn't seem to work (errors).

**How do I get the view to notice I have updated the model?**

Comment: First of all, what angular and ui.bootstrap version are you using? I faced the same problem few weeks ago and found a solution!

Comment: ui.bootstrap 0.12.0 @user2992420

Comment: I think I've found the problem. I thought the $model in `typeahead-on-select($item, $model, $label)` was the typeahead model. But it's probably the model for the specific item in the list. Updating this model was not what I was trying to do. Now I send the name of the model variable to the function and update the model like this `$scope[modelName] = result`. Probably not the best solution, but it's working - I can move on :)

Comment: Can you try to use $parent.modelName instead of modelName in your ng-model attribute? There is a bug which can be solved by this.

Comment: It will point to wrong scope if I do that. What bug are you referring to? Do you have a link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527715/angular-ui-datepicker-doesnt-work-within-a-directive-with-isolate-scope for example

Comment: Show us your async code, are you using angular-aware async (e.g. $http)?

Comment: I use $q, but the problem wasn't the async code but that I updated wrong model. I updated the model for an item in the list and not the ng-model for the typeahead.